# Is it required to update from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, updates, chromebook, arm

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my Samsung Chromebook and I have found that Ubuntu 14.04 does not work with unity on my Chromebook. So do I have to update Ubuntu to 14.04 now or can I continue to use 12.04 for as long as I want? If I don't have to update then will I be subject to many problems? or will I be just fine?

Comment: I thought my question would be more Chromebook targeted as it is Chromebook specific and the other is not also mine has to do with the arm architecture.

Comment: That it's running on Chromebook is not enough of a distinguishing feature (IMO). The answer remains the same: upgrade if you don't have issues, you can stay as long as you want and you'll only get updates till 2017.

Comment: I just thought that the arm architecture would have it own issue set possibly but I might be wrong I am still rather new to Linux and this forum so I did not mean to break any rules or anything sorry if I did.

Comment: It's alright. You need 5 votes (or a mod) to close a question, and I'm just one. Others may disagree and vote against it (and maybe even provide answers), but I'll leave my vote as my opinion.

Comment: If anything, there might be fewer armhf issues, since more packages are likely to have been ported to armhf.